# A connection was successfully established, but error occurred during the login process

Tags: entity-framework-core, scaffolding, db-first

I am facing below error when I am run `scaffold-dbcontext` command.

My command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DESKTOP-C2GIJPS\MSSQLSERVER2016;Database=EmployeeDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"  
         Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

I want to create a `dbContext` class using a database-first approach.

---

3 nuget packages are required to install before running the scaffold command:

1. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
2. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
3. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design